# Twig extend not working

Tags: twig

I feel like this is very stupid problem, but can't solve it.

Installed Twig via composer, version 1.24.2

Trying basic functionality, started from extending templates:

Initialization

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('template');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => 'c_cache',
    'debug' => true,
    'auto_reload' => true,
));
```

Rendering

```
echo $twig->render('layout.twig', array(
'data' => array(
    'title' => 'Page title!',
) ));
```

layout.twig

```
...
<body>

{% block header %}{% endblock %}

</body>
...
```

_header.twig

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{% block header %}
    Hello?
{% endblock %}
```

**Update**

I misunderstood concept of extend, I should use include in this situation.

Comment: How it doesn't work? You're calling `$twig->render('layout.twig', ...)` which renders only `layout.twig`. Maybe you wanted to call `$twig->render('_header.twig', ...)`?

Comment: I want to call layout.twig and include to it partials _header.twig, _body.twig and so on...

Comment: That's not what `extends` is made for. You want probably `include` tag instead, see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Comment: Ok I got it. Misunderstood that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your render should be from _header.twig and not from layout.twig. If you render layout, the block header is empty.

Try to render from _header.twig and you will get the expected result.